# Desktop Settings deleted after update

Tags: updates, login, reboot, desktop-background

I have installed Ubuntu 14.10 multiple times and after a software update my desktop customizations are deleted.

I did a fresh install and about 70 programs were updated following a reboot.

After the reboot, the background is missing and my customizations are gone, and other appearance things seem to have changed.

As of now deactivating the Auto-Login feature works, but when I open a Nautilus window it opens a half screen window every time & it cannot be changed

I found that logging out and logging back in gets me back my desktop mostly normally (there's still a Nautilus malfunction.) Though if I just select my name from the gear icon it asks me to log in and my wallpaper's there, but after it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Answer found!

I was also not able to get a menu by right-clicking on the desktop. Searching on this issue brought the solution, which is to use the Gnome Tweak Tool. I had apparently switched off **Desktop Icons** even though none were selected. Switching this on but leaving no icons selected restored normal behaviour to the desktop and wallpaper.